# Problem 8 from Herstein's Algebra

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

This is a problem 8 from I.N.Herstein's book "Topics in Algebra".

To check that $n$ is a prime number, prove that it is sufficient to show that it is not divisible by any prime number $p$, such that $p\leqslant \sqrt{n}$.

**My proof:** Let $n$ is composite number, then $n=pq$ where $p$-prime and $p\leqslant q$ (it follows from Fundamental theorem of arithmetic). Then $n=pq\geqslant p^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $p\leqslant \sqrt{n}$.

If $n$ is composite then $N$ has prime factor $p\leqslant \sqrt{n}$.

If $n$ has not prime factor such that $p\leqslant \sqrt{n}$ then $n$ is prime number.

Is my approach and solution correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Why do you have doubts?

Comment: @bof, the word "sufficient" makes me doubtful. I think that I have not shown that

Comment: In other words, Herstein is asking you to show that, if $n$ is not divisible by any prime number $p$ such that $p\le\sqrt n,$ then $n$ is a prime number. Where do you think there may be a gap in your reasoning?

Comment: Actually, the problem statement seems slightly inaccurate. Does Herstein consider $1$ a prime number?

Comment: @bof, No he does not!

Comment: @bof, No gap! Thanks for checking :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tackle this is by contradiction. Lets say  $n$ is composite but all its prime factors are more than $\sqrt{n}$. now for $n$ to be composite it atleast needs to have two prime factors but it is not possible as the product of the factors will exceed $n$. Thus by our contradiction wr can show it is sufficient to prove for all primes less than $\sqrt{n}$